# Get Service inside IServiceCollection.AddLogging (C#/.net Core)

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, service

In my .NET Core C# App (not ASP) I build a class to handle my services. You have to configure it like this:

```
MyBaseClass.BuildServiceProvider(serviceCollection =>
                serviceCollection
                    .AddMyConfiguration(out var config)
                    .AddMyEMailService()
                    .AddMyLoggingService(config)
            );
```

The problem is `AddMyLoggingService`, because I don't know how to get other services inside. I already passed in the config, what I think is not what DI wants and now I would also have to pass in the E-Mail service.

The logging service looks like this:

```
public static class ServiceCollectionHelper
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddMyLoggingService(this IServiceCollection coll, IConfiguration config)
        {
            coll.AddLogging(builder =>
                builder
                    .AddConfiguration(config)
                    .AddDebug()
                    .AddEventLog()
                    .AddProvider(new MyTicketLoggerProvider(config))
            );

            return coll;
        }
    }
```

And now `MyTicketLoggerProvider` would need the email service that is injected with `.AddMyEMailService` to create a ticket (by sending an email to the ticket system).

I have no idea what is the best practice for that.

[EDIT] A workaround is that I create a temporary provider inside `AddMyLoggingService`

```
var tmpProvider = coll.BuildServiceProvider();
```

to be able to access the services.

Comment: Your question isnt clear. What does - "The problem is AddMyLoggingService, because I don't know how to get other services inside" mean?